# Is it compulsory to assign null to a reference variable before reassigning a new object in java?

Tags: java, object, dynamic-memory-allocation

Will reassigning a reference variable to null before reassigning it to a new object releases the old memory which it used to hold or is it the work of Garbage Collector?

```
Dog obj = new Dog("d1");
if(obj!=null)
    obj = null; // will this release the memory?
obj = new Dog("d2");
```

OR

```
Dog obj = new Dog("d1");
obj = new Dog("d2");
```

Comment: The work of Garbage Collector.

Comment: Assigning `null` does completily nothing.

Comment: Assigning null first could be useful in the very specific circumstance where you need to let the old object be gc _before_ you create the new object. For instance, if the objects are very big and you're working with very limited memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not compulsory and does in fact not do anything useful.

Assigning `null` to a variable never on its own releases memory. At most it removes one reference that keeps an object reachable and if it was the last reference, then the object can eventually become garbage collected.

But assigning *any other reference* to that variable does the same thing (i.e. remove the reference to the original object), so assigning `null` to it before reassigning it is an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do this! The garbage collector will reclaim the memory either way.

i.e. the following is sufficient:

```
Dog obj = new Dog("d1");
obj = new Dog("d2");
```